# Firebird SQL query parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, firebird

I have this query with some parameters:

```
INSERT INTO " & _
                "szamlaegyenlegek(szamlaszam, halmt, halmk, halme, uzleti_ev, alperiodus_kod, datum, targyt, targyk, targye, kpnem) " & _
                "SELECT DISTINCT " & _
                "szamlaegyenlegek.szamlaszam, (select max(halmt) from (select halmt from szamlaegyenlegek where uzleti_ev=@elozofoper and datum<=@elozovege)), " & _
                "(select max(halmk) from (select halmk from szamlaegyenlegek where uzleti_ev=@elozofoper and datum<=@elozovege)), " & _
                "(select max(halme) from (select halme from szamlaegyenlegek where uzleti_ev=**@elozofoper** and datum<=@elozovege)), " & _
                "@kovuzlev AS uzleti_ev, 0 AS alperiodus_kod, DATE @kovuzlev_kezdes AS datum, " & _
                "0, " & _
                "0, " & _
                "0, '" & KPNEM & "' AS kpnem " & _
                "FROM szamlaegyenlegek INNER JOIN szamlatukor ON szamlaegyenlegek.szamlaszam=szamlatukor.szamlaszam " & _
                "WHERE szamlatip IN ('Aktív', 'Passzív') AND szamlaegyenlegek.szamlaszam=@szamlaszam and uzleti_ev=@elozofoper AND datum<=@elozovege"
```

If I run the query, I get the error:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 497 ?

The column 497 is at **@elozofoper** and datum<=@elozovege)), @kovuzlev AS uzleti_ev.

As you see, all the parameters have a value:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Parameters:
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Name:@kovuzlev    Type:VarChar    Used Value:2014
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Name:@kovuzlev_kezdes    Type:TimeStamp    Used Value:01/01/2014 00:00:00
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Name:@elozofoper    Type:VarChar    Used Value:2013
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Name:@elozovege    Type:VarChar    Used Value:2013.12.31.
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Name:@szamlaszam    Type:VarChar    Used Value:541100
```

It is strange, why I don't get the same error f.e at one line above in the query. I have there the same parameter.

Comment: Does your SQL contain `uzleti_ev=**@elozofoper** and` with stars/asterisks, or did you put them in here to highlight the parameter?  Also, instead of `select max(halme) from (select halme from szamlaegyenlegek where ...` you can just have `select max(halme) from szamlaegyenlegek where ...`

Comment: yes, I used ** to highlight the parameter.

Comment: You'll have to break it down into smaller pieces to fully isolate the problem, and be sure that it isn't just the SQL being too long.

Comment: Firebird itself only supports `?` as (positional) parameter placeholders, which driver are you using?